# About rational Hodge conjecture.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, hodge-theory

What progress has been made to date on the rational Hodge conjecture ?

Can anyone tell us if there is some new books related to Hodge conjecture which explain in detail, the latest development in the field of rational Hodge conjecture ?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Donu Arapura's paper is quite good for your first question:[https://www.math.purdue.edu/~dvb/preprints/chennai.pdf](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Edvb/preprints/chennai.pdf)

As for the second question, I would recommend James Carlson's "period mappings and period domains" which is very nice. And it gives several examples like HC holds for unirational fourfold. I am reading that book now

Comment: The link is obsolete now. It will be helpful to write down the title of the paper, so others can search by title (even without the link).

Comment: @AGlearner The title is "Notes on the Hodge conjecture". I just checked Donu's webpage. It seems that the PDF webpage was deleted. Maybe it is good idea to send him email to request a copy if some one need it.

Comment: Thanks, a quick google search shows me the pdf in [this link](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/NOTES-ON-THE-HODGE-CONJECTURE-Arapura/5bd22f519b83a9d916fd6feb8d9a77667e120f6f) is available.

Comment: @AGlearner Thanks for the information !